# CSS transform: scale to width of parent container?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to have the CSS `transform: scale(n)` attribute scale relative to the size of the parent container. For example:

```
<div id="divA" class="mycontainer">
   <div id="divB" style="width: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

The idea being that if 'divA' is 200px (default size), then 'divB' would maintain its 100px, but if 'divA' was 100px, then 'divB' would become 25px.

The reason I am not specifying percentages in this example is because we need to adjust for third-party components that have their own CSS rules. Redefining them all would lead to a maintenance challenge.

Comment: and if you use scale you will distort the content, not sure if it's better than using percentage

Comment: If you have a specific space around the child element, how about adding padding to the parent and have both at `100%`?

Comment: Can you create a working example of the problem on codepen.io?

Comment: No..a transform has no method of ascertaining **parent** size. It's entirely related to the element to which is it applied...and it's completely **visual**. It does NOT affect layout at all.